# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'. | Flutter | Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'am trying to fetch some details from my firebase database, the below is my code. Here i'am getting the error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.` in the line `double.parse(dataSnapshot.value!['pickUp']['latitude'].toString());`. What is the issue??

```
DatabaseReference newRequestsRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Ride Requests');

 void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId, BuildContext context) {
    newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((value) {
      var dataSnapshot = value.snapshot;
     
      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        double pickUpLocationLat =
            double.parse(dataSnapshot.value!['pickUp']['latitude'].toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void retrieveRideRequestInfo(
      String rideRequestId, BuildContext context) async {
    newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((value) {
      var dataSnapshot = value.snapshot;
      final map = dataSnapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        double pickUpLocationLat =
            double.parse(map['pickUp']['latitude'].toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

I Found the solution just make it map `final map = dataSnapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there is a nested Map in `pickup` maybe you could try:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> pickup = dataSnapshot.value!['pickUp'];
double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(pickup['latitude'].toString());
```

Also if you could add a screenshot of your document model or the debugger value of snapshot.value it could help