# Flutter firebase not able to display snapshot data due to object operator issues

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am having trouble displaying data from a firebase cloud firestore linked to a flutter project.

I keep getting this error, and I see that it's a common occurrence in other projects. However, I am not sure how to fix it in my case. I see that some other projects involve specifying Map<String,dynamic> but I'm not sure how it applies for my code.

I keep getting this error of:

> 'The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
>
> Try defining the operator '[]'.'.

Here is my streambuilder.
The main issue lies in `doc.data()!['itemname']`. I have tried adding "as String" but it still doesn't work.

I know that once I fix one of the `doc.data()!['itemname']` issue, the rest can be fixed by implementing the same solution.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('transactions')
                  .doc(Provider.of<Login>(context, listen: false).email)
                  .collection('transactions')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return DataTable(
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Date'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Time'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Currency'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Item'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Amount'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Entry'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Comment'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Edit'),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text('Delete'),
                    ),
                  ],
                  rows: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                    return DataRow(
                      cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy')
                                .format(DateTime.parse(doc.data()!['date'])),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            DateFormat('h:mm a')
                                .format(DateTime.parse(doc.data()['time'])),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(doc.data()!['currency'] as String),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(doc.data()['item']),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(doc.data()['amount']),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(doc.data()['entry']),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(doc.data()['comment']),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                            onPressed: () {
                              userSelectDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                  .format(DateTime.parse(doc.data()['date']));
                              userSelectTime = DateFormat('h:mm a')
                                  .format(DateTime.parse(doc.data()['time']));
                              userEntry = doc.data()['entry'];
                              userAmount = doc.data()['amount'];
                              commentTransaction = doc.data()['comment'];
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'edit_transaction');
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () {
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('transactions')
                                  .doc(
                                      Provider.of<Login>(context, listen: false)
                                          .email)
                                  .collection('transactions')
                                  .doc(doc.data()['id'])
                                  .delete();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Example of my data in firebase:
[image: data image]

I appreciate any guidance and tips!

References:

[After updating cloud firestore: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob)
[The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. Try defining the operator '[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615606/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object-function-try-defining)

[The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'. | Flutter | Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434546/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object-try-defining-the-operator)

[FLUTTER The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547592/flutter-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Text(doc.data()['item'])`

With:

```
Text(doc.get('item'))
```

Comment: Thank you, i no longer get the error but my items still does not show